Does a therapist's confidentiality cover past crimes?
I was watching an episode of House, in which Dr. Chase purposefully botches treating a patient because the patient is a genocidal dictator.  Chase goes to a priest for emotional support, but if he had gone to see a therapist instead, would the therapist be obligated to report him?  I know therapists are obligated to report patients who are planning future violence, but what about patients who have already committed violence?
The show takes place in the US, but I would appreciate answers from any jurisdiction.

In the U.S., this is a matter of state law.
Most U.S. jurisdictions have a privilege and confidentiality obligation for psychotherapy, which is just like the protections for talking to an attorney or a priest. See, e.g., Colorado Revised Statutes § 13-90-107 (listing privileges from testifying), especially subsection (1)(h) which states:

A licensed psychologist, professional counselor, marriage and family
therapist, social worker, or addiction counselor, an unlicensed
psychotherapist, a certified addiction counselor, a psychologist
candidate registered pursuant to section 12-245-304 (3), a marriage
and family therapist candidate registered pursuant to section
12-245-504 (4), a licensed professional counselor candidate registered
pursuant to section 12-245-604 (4), or a person described in section
12-245-217 shall not be examined without the consent of the
licensee's, certificate holder's, registrant's, candidate's, or
person's client as to any communication made by the client to the
licensee, certificate holder, registrant, candidate, or person or the
licensee's, certificate holder's, registrant's, candidate's, or
person's advice given in the course of professional employment; nor
shall any secretary, stenographer, or clerk employed by a licensed
psychologist, professional counselor, marriage and family therapist,
social worker, or addiction counselor, an unlicensed psychotherapist,
a certified addiction counselor, a psychologist candidate registered
pursuant to section 12-245-304 (3), a marriage and family therapist
candidate registered pursuant to section 12-245-504 (4), a licensed
professional counselor candidate registered pursuant to section
12-245-604 (4), or a person described in section 12-245-217 be
examined without the consent of the employer of the secretary,
stenographer, or clerk concerning any fact, the knowledge of which the
employee has acquired in such capacity; nor shall any person who has
participated in any psychotherapy, conducted under the supervision of
a person authorized by law to conduct such therapy, including group
therapy sessions, be examined concerning any knowledge gained during
the course of such therapy without the consent of the person to whom
the testimony sought relates.

Usually, psychotherapists are not mandatory reporters.
With respect to the privilege of a therapist for minor victim of child abuse, see, e.g., L.A.N. et al. v. L.M.B., 2013 CO 6.

What about a practitioner of hydrotherapy?

The presence of "unlicensed psychotherapist" in this list is a tad strange.  Every other profession has some sort of documented qualification required.  I assume the law elsewhere makes it clear who qualifies as an unlicensed psychotherapist?

@zibadawatimmy https://dpo.colorado.gov/UnlicensedPsychotherapy

@ohwilleke Thanks. That oddly might actually make it more confusing, though.  haha  Seems like this BUP acts exactly as a licensing board for psychotherapists.  Seems it's not quite as demanding a "license" process as evidently certification or simply registration with the BUP qualifies for legal practice.  How peculiar.  I might have to try to figure out why they organized things this way.  All other regulated mental health care professionals are evidently "licensed" in the law, but not psychotherapists...

No
australia
Nor does a member of the clergy.
However, both professions (among others), are somewhat protected in that the Attorney General needs to approve a prosecution under s316 for “Concealing serious indictable offence”.
You can read the law yourself, but in a nutshell, any adult that believes that a serious indictable offence has been committed is committing a crime if they do not report it to the police without reasonable excuse. Professional privilege and confidentiality is only a reasonable excuse for lawyers and no one else.
The regulation lists certain professions where failing to report is still a crime, but prosecution is at the discretion of the Attorney General. Needless to say, this is contentious, particularly with respect to the Catholic confessional and health professionals, but despite several Law Commission reviews, the law has been unchanged for more than 25 years.
Assuming here that the “therapist” is actually a registered psychologist, and not someone who just calls themselves a therapist. Therapist is not a protected term in Australia, psychologist is.
